# Load several views in one page

Tags: convertigo

I would like to print the content of several views of my couchDB database inside a page.

I have several listContainers in my page and each listContainers must print the content of one view.

To do that I added an "onDidLoad" event to my page which triggers several QueryViews (one QueryView per view).

I correctly binded the content of each ListContainer with its corresponding view.
My problem is that all the lists print the same content which is the content of the last loaded view. All the views seem to be loaded but only the last view loaded is taken into account.

Is it possible to have several QueryViews for one page and how can I load the content of different views inside one page ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to have multiple **Query view** components in one Page. Use the **Marker** property to set a different value for each component. In the MobileComponent Source you will find all your views marked as **myView#myMarker**. Select corresponding view markers for your listContainers.